# "Wrong number of arguments to CELL. Expected 2 arguments, but got 1 arguments." idk what i'm doing wrong

Tags: google-sheets

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C8<>"",IF(AND(J8<>"",CELL("address")=ADDRESS(ROW(C8),COLUMN(C8))),NOW(),IF(CELL("address")<>ADDRESS(ROW(C8),COLUMN(C8)),J8,NOW())),"")), 1, 1)

The above code is what google sheets changed it to when I imported it from excel, it works fine while in excel but once I import it in google docs it tells me that it only gets 1 argument. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to add or remove comma's and or brackets and nothing is working, am very confused

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: How does one upload an excel sheet in a comment?
So the desired outcome is that when I input data in specified column it should automatically add the date and or time in another specified column.

Comment: not the excel, your sample google sheet url would suffice

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1arf9kc59CtPh5FHTiyrGHYgaW0iZ_WrMH6hUkxMX4oU/edit?usp=sharing

Would this suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Added the following formula to your sample sheet at `Cell J5`. Please do test it out and let us know if its working as intended.

```
=arrayformula(IF(C5:C<>"",IF(J5:J="",NOW(),J5:J),""))
```